# How to sync file trees on windows to a local hard drive with complex exclusions

Tags: windows-10, mirroring, exclude

I'm looking for a possibility to one-way sync directory trees on windows from multiple hard drives to a external hard drive for backup. The source trees contain a lot of complex redundant files which i'd like to exclude with as little effort as possible.

Wsl is not an option.

It's basically [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1749014/is-there-something-robocopy-like-but-with-gitignore-or-regex-exclude-style), but i tried to formulate it according to the rules and not as a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem#:%7E:text=The%20XY%20problem%20is%20asking,trouble%2C%20you%20ask%20about%20Y.).

Comment: I do this with Sync Back Pro - Backup Option.

Comment: Have you tested with Robocopy yet and use the `/XF` and/or `/XD` parameters? If you run `robocopy /?` you will see `/XF file [file]... :: eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards` and `/XD dirs [dirs]... :: eXclude Directories matching given names/paths` so this may be a simple starting point and a simple way to build out exclusion files and folders for your need. Please [edit] your post and add the logic you are trying and tell what trouble you are having with it. That's likley all you need to do it try something and show your work but this may be a starting point for you.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle robocopy is what i'm using atm but the exclusion patterns are messy, for one because the directory exclusions don't accept compositions. F.e. i need to exclude all release* folders directly or indirectly below folder x, but not below folder y, where x and y are both somewhere in the tree. And for the other, because the file exclusions also should be limited to certain paths, f.e. excluding *.exe for one path and everything below, but not for others.

Comment: Rather than using Robocopy itself to do the exclusions, use another utility of filter to get the file list, and then pass that to robocopy to do the movement. Or, a combination of the two.